# nslookup fails while dig succeeds with private Route 53 hosted zone

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I have set up a private AWS Route 53 hosted zone.

If I run nslookup on the newly added entry, I receive an error:

```
$nslookup search.syndey.recap
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find search.syndey.recap: NXDOMAIN
```

However, if I request the same thing from dig, I get a (correct) result

```
$ dig search.sydney.recap

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> search.sydney.recap
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56763
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;search.sydney.recap.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
search.sydney.recap.    300 IN  CNAME   i-03cd02d0d3695af77.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal.
i-03cd02d0d3695af77.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal. 60 IN A 172.32.38.206

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 23 09:15:48 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 129
```

They both appear to me to be using the same source (127.0.0.53), why might they be giving different results?  What should I look for to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have a misspelling in your query.

You’re querying syndey instead of sydney.

Answer (score 1):

Nslookup is looking for the domain search.syndey.recap. NXDOMAIN stands for a non-existent domain

You could do

```
Nslookup -type=any syndey.recap`
```

That should also give the search record

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `nslookup -type=any sydney.recap` also returned an NXDOMAIN.  `nslookup -type=any recap` returned the standard list of AWS private nameservers, so at least one bit looks like it's working.

Comment: Is it sydney or syndey?

Comment: @GregW excellent spotting.  Correcting that now gives a IP address out of `nslookup`.  I swear that I tested this with the correct spelling and that it previously failed.  However I'm going to go hide in my corner now until I get over my embarrassment.

Comment: I’ll add it as an answer